# Why is an array sometimes used as a key in JSON when this array has only one entry that contains a dictionary?

Tags: arrays, json

I am learning some JSON and stumbled upon this JSON weather data for London from a call to the OpenWeatherMap API.

See the following JSON string:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 802,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "scattered clouds",
      "icon": "03d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 9.69,
    "pressure": 1023,
    "humidity": 57,
    "temp_min": 9,
    "temp_max": 11
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 5.7,
    "deg": 290
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 40
  },
  "dt": 1492330800,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5091,
    "message": 0.0085,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1492318900,
    "sunset": 1492369187
  },
  "id": 2643743,
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200
}
```

For the "weather" key, an array with only one entry is used, which contains a dictionary. What is the purpose of this? Why not simply use just a dictionary as a value to the "weather" key like it is done for the "coord" key or the "main" key?

Comment: Maybe the developer wanted to be able to handle combination of multiple weather conditions, like sunny & windy.

Answer (score 0):

You will have an array if there is a possibility that you would want to have zero, one or more entries.

If you transmitted two weather dictionaries in an array, and one weather dictionary just as a dictionary without an array, that would have several negative aspects: One, the sender would have to distinguish between one and more dictionaries. Second, the receiver would have to handle both dictionaries and arrays. Third, the receiver might be led to believe that there cannot be more than one dictionary, and might not have code to handle it.

Sometimes it's rare to have more than one item. Take a database of books: Some books have more than one author, but it's rare. Some books have more than one translator, but it's rare, but many have no translator at all. But you want to be able to handle all the cases in your code.